# $\mu^*$ measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory

A subset E of X is said to be $\mu^*$ measurable if

$\mu^*(A) = \mu^* (A \cap E) + \mu^*(A \backslash E)$ for all subsets A of X.

In other words what this says is a set E is $\mu^*$ measurable if E and its compliment are sufficiently separated that they divide an arbitrary set A additively.

What is the intuition behind this definition? What is this saying?

I know $\mu^*$ means outer measure but what does the term $\mu^*$ measurable mean?

Does it just mean that the outer measure of a subset can be found?

Comment: Sets with that property are by *definition* $\mu^{*}$-measurable, so this definition tells you exactly what $\mu^{*}$-measurable means. The collection of these sets is a $\sigma$-algebra, and $\mu^{*}$ restricted to that collection is a measure on it.

Comment: Should that not be $\mu^*$ restricted to that collection is an outer measure on it?

Comment: No. $\mu^*$ is an [outer measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure#Formal_definitions) and  restricted to the collection  of $\mu^*$-measurable set (wich is a $\sigma$-algebra) it is a [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Definition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People would just say a set is measurable if Caratheodory condition is satisfied. I feel you always confuse terms. I guess you need change a book, like Royden's

As regard the intuition of Caratheodory condition, it bothered me (and still) and I think it can be a quite deep problem:-( Here is the best explanation I can find [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/34029)

Comment: Dont you mean outer measurable because it is $\mu^*$?

Comment: $\mu^*$ is a quite standard symbol in real analysis which stands for outer measure. People don't say "outer measurable". They just say a set is measurable if this set satisfies the Caratheodory condition.

Comment: But dont they get confused with the proper measure?

Comment: What do you mean by "they"?

Comment: I mean is it not confusing to talk of the outer measure as measurable ? Because than their is something else called measure i.e the proper measure?

Comment: This is what I mean. People don't say $\mu^*$-measurable, just say measurable. I don't know which source you get this term:-(. A measurable set is a set satisfying Caratheodory condition.

Comment: Bartle element of integration contains so much weird notation haha

Comment: How would you show the set X is measurable?

Comment: The expresion $\mu*$-measurable is actually used, especially when there is more than one outer measure involved.  Also note that the notation $\mu^*$ for outer measure may be confusing, because it suggests the outer measure may have being defined from a measure / pre-measure $\mu$, and, in fact, that may not be true. There are outer outer measures which are not produced from any measure / pre-measure.