# While proving Vitali set is not Lebesgue measurable...

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

So in the typical proof as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1869015/941576), we show that any two sets $V$ and $V+q$, where $q$ is a rational, are either disjoint or equal. While I was able to prove this claim using contradiction and leveraging the equivalence relation we defined, I can think of some counterexamples:
$V= [0.2,0.9]$; $q= 0.1$; $V+q=[0.3,1]$.
Here clearly $V$ and $V+q$ are not disjoint, neither equal. Is there something in the definition that I am missing?

Comment: The construction of a Vitali set $V$ is a quotient by the relation $x\sim y \Leftrightarrow x-y \in \mathbb{Q}$. So not only is your set not Vitali (e.g., $0.2$ and $0.9$ have a rational distance, so only one can be in the set), but if it were, $V+q = V$, since for any $v \in V$, $v+q-v \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Neither of your $V$-s are Vitali sets, because a Vitali set is a set with the properties that: 1) for all $x,y\in V$ either $x=y$ or $x-y\notin \Bbb Q$ and 2) for all $x\in \Bbb R$ there is some $y\in V$ such that $x-y\in\Bbb Q$.