# Crucial step in proof of `measure problem' has me baffled

Tags: measure-theory

I was following along a Y-T video proving that there is no useful measure on the power set of $\mathbb{R}$. The proof is too long to lay out here but I'm certain that most respondents here will recognize it if I just describe it.

The proof starts by pulling all the rational numbers from (0,1], creating little `boxes' along the interval. Next construct a set $A$ that contains one and only one point from each box. Then create a sequence, $A_n$ by adding a rational r from (-1,1), jogging $A$ left and right in (-1,2]. Then we take the countable union of the $A_n$, and here's where I lose the plot. The claim, setting up the final blow in the proof, is that

(0,1] $\subseteq \{\cup A_n, n \in \mathbb{N} \} \subseteq (-1,2]$

I get the RHS but the LHS looks exactly wrong to me. (0,1] contains all the reals and by construction the term in the middle is devoid of the rational numbers. How can the term in the middle contain (0,1]?

Comment: What are these 'boxes'? Link to YT video?

Comment: The boxes are the sets where we say $x\sim y$ if $x-y \in \mathbb{Q}$. That is, if values only differ by a rational we consider them equivalent. The link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ur3ofJ61bpk

Comment: I found a discussion of the proof I am troubled by at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696248/intuitive-explanation-of-why-the-power-set-of-mathbbr-is-too-big-for-the. It's from nearly 6 years ago. Seems the set I called A is a Vitali set - nice to know. However, the discussion did not address my  problem (see question). Any help on this one line in the proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My claim about the middle term is wrong. While it's true that the set $A$ is constructed to exclude the rational numbers in (0,1], the $A_n$ are constructed by adding the rational numbers in (-1,1] to $A$, thus restoring those removed.

This closes the question unless someone has something else to add.